# Why can't I change my actionbar text color?

Tags: java, android, colors, tabs, android-actionbar

I used this generator to create a custom theme for my app:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

But there is one thing that i want to change, that this generator does not support:
The textcolor of the actionbar.

I tried doing this manually with this code:

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Bessel" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F8F8FF</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

But the textcolor of my actionbar remains unchanged. Any tips?

Update:

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Bessel" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Your.ActionBar</item>


</style>
<style name="Your.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_bessel</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_bessel</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_bessel</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Bessel</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F8F8FF</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be applying `android:titleTextStyle` to a style that is inherent of `Widget.ActionBar`. So, it looks like in your case that would be `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`.

```
<style name="Your.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

Then apply your `ActionBar` style in your root theme using `android:actionBarStyle`.

```
<style name="Theme.Bessel" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Your.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

---

To change the tab text color, you need a theme that inherits `Widget.ActionBar.TabText`, in your case that looks like it'll be `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText`. Then to apply the style use `android:actionBarTabTextStyle` in your root theme.

```
<style name="Theme.Bessel" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Your.Widget.ActionBar.TabText</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Widget.ActionBar.TabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F8F8FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried it with your code(Updated it in the post), but the textcolor is still unchanged.

Comment: @user2051194 You're not using `android:actionBarStyle` in your root theme.

Comment: @user2051194 You still aren't using `android:actionBarStyle` in your root theme. In `Theme.Bessel`, change `android:titleTextStyle` to `android:actionBarStyle`.

Comment: Sorry, i just forgot to update that part in the post
The problem still remains

Comment: See this link for detail on how to change action bar text color, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText

Comment: @user2051194 You still aren't doing it correctly. You need to have the `android:` modifier in front of the attribute.

Comment: Which attribute do you mean?

Comment: @user2051194 `actionBarStyle`. In `Theme.Bessel` change `actionBarStyle` to `android:actionBarStyle`.

Comment: @adneal
Sorry, just forgot to update that part again :/

Comment: @user2051194 Then your styles are correct. Apply `Theme.Bessel` in your `AndroidManifest` to your `application` tag or each individual `activity` tag if you don't want your entire app to inherit the theme.

Comment: I know what the problem is now. 
The code works. But i don't want to change the color of the title. I want to change the color of the tabs that are included in the actionbar. 
Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @user2051194 I made an edit to my post explaining how to change the tab text color.

Comment: It works now! :)
Thank you very much for your patience with me :)